# How can light be used to move an object

Tags: forces

If light can push an object, what would have to be done with it to push a 1lb.  square  object across a polished surface?

Comment: [Solar sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) principle ? you need to know the surface friction, the sail efficiency and the wavelenght to compute the intensity. Probably, vacuum too

Comment: you can also redirect the light to a photoelectric device, stock the electric energy in a battery to fed an engine to push the square object :)